# RCGA solving in MATLAB implementation

Tags: matlab

Now, I would like to practice some problem solving by use RCGA (Real Code Genetic Algorithms) in MATLAB. Could any helper provide me some example project matlab files about that ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an [article](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/digest/2005/nov/genalgo.html) a few years ago on an application of genetic algorithms in MATLAB, which comes with example data and MATLAB code. Although the example doesn't use real-coding, it does demonstrate how to apply a custom chromosomal coding, so perhaps it would be a starting point for you that you could adapt.